# Wrong results with mf2pt1

Tags: fonts, metafont

I tried to make a vector font font of the Metafont sources of cmr10, but look ...

[image]

The are only some correct glyphs, almost everything looks wrong.

```
mf2pt1 cmr10.mf
```

Can you tell me what went wrong?

When I try

```
mf2pt1 grmn1000.mf
```

to get a greek font, it is even worse. Many error messages and no file produced.

[image]

Comment: Look at the glyphs. They are wrong.

Comment: the greek has been moved from 0-30 control character slot, but otherwise your image looks more or less as expected

Comment: I would like to have everything in every optical size and I interpolated a "Computer Modern Medium" in Metafont, so the Type 1 Computer Modern is useless for me.

Comment: It does not look exactly as cmr10, many glyphs are much too thin.

Comment: possibly, hard to tell from  a screenshot. the original type1 conversions spent some effort to tweak the mf mode to get suitably thick strokes

Comment: I added a screenshot that shows the "digit 7". It is very ugly.

Comment: getting good outlines from metafont is _hard_ most (many?) conversions do not convert the mf paths, but instead make a high resolution bitmap, then produce outline by tracing the bitmap